# CSS position issue

Tags: css, css-float

basically i have div with width of 960px and it has navigation on right hand, the navigation works fine, just the last sub navigation shows content extended to 960px, so i was wondering if somehow i can push it to left side, without pushing top navigation with it, i been trying but it dont work. following is the example and css code

> navigation, the last black line is the
>   end of 960px;

[image]

> screenshot for navigation question two
>   (question from comment)

[image]

css code example

```
#topNav {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
    #topNav li {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        line-height:1.5em;
        padding: 0 .5em;
    }
    #topNav a span {
        clear: both;
    }
    #topNav ul ul {
        display:none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        right: 0;
    }
    #topNav ul ul li {
        float:none;
        white-space:nowrap;
        position: relative;
        margin:0;
    }
    #topNav li.active {
        height: 50px;
        background-color:#FFF;
        border-top:#666 1px solid;
        border-right:#666 1px solid;
        border-left:#666 1px solid;
        border-bottom:#FFF 1px solid;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    #topNav ul ul.active {
        display: block;
        background-color:#F8F8F8;
        border:#666 1px solid;
        margin-top: -1px;
        margin-right: -1px;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

html 5 code

```
<nav id="topNav">
            <ul>
              <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" title="Nav Link 3">Everyone</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" title="Profile">Profile</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" title="Account" >Account</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" title="Edit Freinds">Edit Friends</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="Account Settings">Account Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="Privacy Settings">Privacy Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="Help Center">Help Center</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" title="Logout">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul> 
              </li>
              <li><a href="#" title="Layouts" class="active">Layouts</a>
                    <ul class="active">
                        <li><a href="#" title="Default">Default Layout</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Default Elements</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Default Form</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Media Detail</a></li>
                    </ul>        
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Try `left:-100px` in `#topNav ul ul li` or `#topNav ul ul`.

Comment: you want to push to the left only the last submenu or all subs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the following:

```
#topNav ul ul {
    right: 0;
}
```

Rather than `left: 0;`. This **should** make it line up with the right hand side of the top menu item (Layouts in this case), rather than the left hand side.

Comment: lol funny, i tried that in dreamweaver, which showed incorrect and all the way to right, but it worked fine in browser now lol..

Comment: @Basit never trush Dreamweaver's WYSIWYG

Comment: @Basit - proves the point that one should never trust Dreamweaver; if you want to see how your code looks in a browser, you have to use a browser (and make sure you test in all the browsers, not just your favourite one)

Comment: ya i do, just on this small thing, i thought lets try.. silly me. anyway, i head another question related to this question. im trying to put border around the selected link with ul, i manage to do so, but i cant get the z-index work, so it hides half of the top border of ul. please see my new css update on the question. and for quick thing, im tring to make navigation like facebook one.

Comment: @Basit - Can you update your question with a new screenshot as well please?

Comment: @Bliar i have added the new screenshot, i just need that top half border to disappear, so it looks like a solid box with the selected menu. just like in facebook.

Comment: @Basit - You need to give the "Layouts" menu item a bottom border of the background colour and make sure that it's at least +1 z-index to the UL and LI of the subnav. You have the right sort of CSS, just on the wrong elements.

Comment: ya i did that with #topNav li.active (which is top li, not subnav) and i gave white for testing purpose, so black hides.. but not working :(

Comment: @Basit - Ahh sorry, missed that part. Try moving the negative margin onto the active top li (margin-bottom: -1px;) rather than margin-top: -1px on the subnav. Other than that, I can't really help you. You're doing the right sort of thing. Just a matter of getting it all on the right elements the right way around. Some google searches for "tabbed css menu" might help a bit as well.

Comment: all the tabbed or navigation i see examples of are easy to do and none of them are exactly same as im doing. tabbed dont have sub menu and the menu examples, they all have matching borders or no borders, nothing similar to what im doing.

Comment: @Basit - Ok, I've been playing around with a test file. Remove all of your current z-indexes and add `z-index: -1;` to `#topNav ul ul`. You'll then probably need to adjust the position and colour of the lis, but it looks like that should work for you (it puts the subnav ul behind the other elements).

Comment: actually i got it working with fixing the position on a.active and just need to fix the padding and thats it. Thank you for helping :)